# Bluetooth pairing with pre-shared-key

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w, android

I want to pair my Raspberry Pi zero with my android phone using a pre-shared key. By using bluetoothctl I can pair both devices but not with a pre-shared key only either with no key at all or with a randomly generated key that I have to provide to the pi zero.

My plan is to run the pi zero completely headless and I want to pair new smartphones with the pi without the need to enter anything on the pi (just-works pairing is not an option).

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this?

Thank you